# Python - gtk3 add stock icons to Gtk.Buttons

Tags: python, icons, gtk3

I'm new to GTK3 *(I prefer `wxWidgets`)*, and I can't load a stock icon to a gtk.button...

This is my attempt:

```
image = Gtk.Image()
pb = Pixbuf.new_from_stock(Gtk.STOCK_OPEN)

self.browse_button = Gtk.Button(label="")
self.browse_button.set_from_pixbuf(pb)
```

This is how it is done on `wxWidgets` (much more simpler):

```
self.browse_button = wx.BitmapButton( self, wx.ID_ANY, wx.ArtProvider.GetBitmap( wx.ART_FILE_OPEN, wx.ART_MENU ), wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, wx.BU_AUTODRAW )
```

any help?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try:

```
image = Gtk.Image(stock=Gtk.STOCK_OPEN)
self.browse_button = Gtk.Button(label="Some Label", image=image)
```

See the [documentation](http://python-gtk-3-tutorial.readthedocs.org/en/latest/button_widgets.html).

Comment: OK, you didn't say you wanted your own label with a stock icon... see edit.

Answer (score 4):

Like Ptomato did, but with no label and using one line :

```
self.btnOpen = Gtk.Button(None,image=Gtk.Image(stock=Gtk.STOCK_OPEN))
```